# Dev C++ doesn't display all my outputs

Tags: c++, output, buffer, dev-c++

i just finished my c++ program and everything is working just fine !
The thing is Dev C++ does NOT display all my outputs , but only a number of em , while cropping the others(the first ones) ! If i remove the last cout's , i will get the right outputs ! Any help please to get all my outputs !!?`

Comment: Without the use of a crystal ball I can not help.. Please show a minimum amount of code that shows the problem.

Comment: Whats a crystal ball ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball

Comment: Make sure you print `endl` after the output.

Comment: @Barmar - I'll bet the code uses `endl` after every line of output. Regardless, that's probably not the problem. It sounds like the output is scrolling off the top of the screen.

Comment: @PeteBecker I suspect you're right -- I just noticed that he says that the missing ones are the first ones, not the last ones.

Comment: How can your program be working just fine if you can't see all of your output?

Answer (score 1):

If your program writes more lines of output than there are on the screen, the first lines will scroll off the top of the screen. If you remove the last ones, then the first ones won't scroll off the top, and you'll be able to see them.

Comment: I wonder what kind of environment he's running in that doesn't allow scolling back to the earlier output.